# Access HTML content of SSRS report Using Java webservice for LifeRay portal

Tags: java, ssrs-2008, liferay, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have developed a SSRS report which shows the log details. I want to show the HTML content in Liferay Portlet for that i need to develop Java webservices. Could you please suggest the best possible solution to achieve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Liferay Service Buider](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/12557680). Please have a look at the link and you can create a Liferay service, which can be a remote (web) service, Code the localServiceImpl class of your service and get the SSRS data, once you have the data, it is up to you to display data on portlet view or store into db for later use.